# How can I design a window too look just like this pop-up in windows 7 taskbar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, forms

I need a rounded thick border and same colors. Is this available somewhere in Visual Studio Forms?

[image]

Comment: please also put a screenshot of how your current Windows form looks like... I think this behaviour is default in Windows 7, or have I misunderstood your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one:

[image: Examle]

1. Add a new form.
2. SetControlBox = false.
3. ShowIcon = false.
4. SetGripStyle = Hide.
5. Add the three required buttons using docking functionality.

I hope this helps.

Note. When you run this it will look exaclty as you require. Then you will have to worry about positioning, but that is another question...

Comment: Thanks! The window is good now, but I can't seem to work ouy what color to use for the bottom part of the frame to give that effect